# Similar file management as a one-click install but for local server

Tags: php, wordpress

When I download `Wordpress` from their site, it comes in a folder called "wordpress" and in this folder there are 3 more folders called "wp-admin", "wp-content" and "wp-includes" with numerous PHP files. When I work locally my file management looks like this:

`Site > wordpress > wp-content > ...`and so on

My own web domain has a one-click install for `Wordpress` which results in the file management to look like:

`site > wp-content > ..`and so on

When I am working, I would like to be able to have exactly the same file management as my domain has instead of my local server's way. Changing this as per wordpress is very tedious!

How can I have the same folder structure without a wordpress folder in between?

Answer (score 0):

When you unzip the download file you move all the folders up a level and then install it.  They don't have to stay in the default 'wordpress' folder.